# Overriding fork setting for custom SBT task

Tags: scala, sbt

I'm implementing a custom task in SBT which runs some external Java class. I'm using the `runner` task to do it.

```
myCustomTask := {
  val mainClass: String = ???
  val classpath: Seq[File] = ???
  val options: Seq[String] = ???
  runner.value.run(mainClass, classpath, options, streams.value.log)
}
```

I'd like to configure this task so that it runs in separate JVM. Normally, this is configured using `fork` option which is then referenced by the `runner` task.

I'd like to configure the fork only for my custom task. I tried doing this:

```
fork in myCustomTask := true
```

but it doesn't work. The `runner` task still gets the unchanged value of `fork`.

I also tried adjusting the task itself by using `(runner in myCustomTask)` instead of just `runner`, but this doesn't help either.

How do I set `fork` to `true` only for `myCustomTask`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally settled with something like this:

```
fork in myCustomTask := true,
myCustomTask := {
  val mainClass: String = ???
  val classpath: Seq[File] = ???
  val options: Seq[String] = ???
  val runner = initScoped(myCustomTask.scopedKey, Defaults.runnerInit).value
  runner.run(mainClass, classpath, options, streams.value.log)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `fullRunTask`, as documented at http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Faq.html#How+can+I+create+a+custom+run+task%2C+in+addition+to+%3F

Comment: This is nice, but I don't like the fact that it only works with tasks returning `Unit`.

Comment: It does not really allow you to configure ForkOptions.