# Override sbt's `fork` setting

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt, fork

I have an Akka app that has a `fork := true` setting in `build.sbt`. So when I need to debug code I set it manually to `false`. That is something which is easy to forget.

Is there a way to override the `fork` setting from command line? For example when running `sbt clean run`. I've read that one can create a separate task and [override fork](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31749909/3264147) just for that task. In latter case how would the `clean run` task look like?

**Update:** Sorry for the confusion. Following Marko's reply I realized that my ticket was incomplete. I would like a way to set this in a non-interactive shell. Right now I have an IntelliJ sbtTask (which also takes environment variables etc.) for which I just click the debug button to run the app. The task itself has only two words in it - `clean run`, but should need to create a separate one that would be fine.

Answer (score 3):

Consider `set` command, for example from within sbt shell

```
set fork := false; clean; run
```

change will stick [until](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Command-Line-Reference.html#Commands+for+managing+the+build+definition)

> sbt is restarted, the build is reloaded, or the setting is overridden by another set command or removed by the session command

Comment: Is there a way to set in a non-interactive shell? I would like to have a single IntelliJ sbtTask for which I would just click the debug button. I will update my question - my apologies.

Comment: This is the answer. I needed this for debugging and the only thing I also needed to do for IntelliJ one-click debugging was start the sbt shell with the debugging port open:
`sbt -J-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005`. Verify the debug listener with `sockstat -4 -l` and verify the unforked state with `pstree -p {whatever your shell PID is}`

Answer (score 0):

Mario's answer is very good, but I was curious if there was a single line instruction that I could share with my team. I think I've finally found it thanks to [this FAQ item](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Faq.html#How+can+I+create+a+custom+run+task%2C+in+addition+to+%3F) in Sbt documentation.

In `build.sbt` you can add the following:

```scala
lazy val runWithForkFalse = taskKey[Unit]("Run application with `set fork:= false` for debugging purpose.")

runWithForkFalse / fork := false

fullRunTask(runWithForkFalse, Compile, "com.Main")
```

Then in InelliJ you can create a Sbt task that has only two words `clean runWithForkFalse` and click on their debug icon. You can also of course just run `sbt clean runWithForkFalse` from command line.